# Downloading html as string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to download a webpage as string. Can someone please explain why the following code doesn't work?

```
    Dim URL As String = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim data As Stream = client.OpenRead(URL)
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(data)
    Dim str As String = ""
    str = reader.ReadLine()
    Do While str.Length > 0
        Console.WriteLine(str)
        str = reader.ReadLine()
    Loop
```

When I run it it never goes inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot...

```
  Dim URL As String = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
  Dim html As String = New WebClient().DownloadString(URL)
```

**Better Solution** (Releases resources that the network stack is using. Also ensure's (hope) the CLR cleans these up when needed.)

```
 Using client As New WebClient()
   html = client.DownloadString(URL)
 End Using
```

Comment: Good, please see update. Also if this has helped please mark as answer.